# wmic OS list Full seems broken

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, wmic

I try that command on my Windows 7 x64 with updates.

```
wmic os list FULL
```

It fails with error.

```
Node - [pc name]
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query
```

Comment: What output from `wmic context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with the `alias` command.

> `C:\>wmic`
>   `wmic:root\cli>alias os list FULL`

You may want to use `/FORMAT:Table` if you plan on being able to easily view the output.

Answer (score 1):

use `wmic os get *`
and `wmic os get * /format:value`